# My jquery banner is not shrinking for responsive?what property shall I need to use here?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My jquery banner is not shrinking?what property I have to use here?In my mobile.css I have used class .banner width:100%.even though It is not shrinking for width 260px.I want to know what property do i need to used.check this link. I have hosted in webserver.  http://vkacademy.in/banner/

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="slider/css/skitter.styles.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="slider/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="slider/js/jquery.skitter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.box_skitter_large').skitter({
            theme: 'clean',
            numbers_align: 'center',
            progressbar: true, 
            dots: true, 
            preview: true
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="banner">
        <div class="border_box">
            <div class="box_skitter box_skitter_large">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#cubeRandom"><img src="slider/images/example/1.jpg" class="circles" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>One</p></div></li>
                    <li><a href="#block"><img src="slider/images/example/2.jpg" class="circles" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>Two</p></div></li>
                    <li><a href="#cubeRandom"><img src="slider/images/example/3.jpg" class="circles" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>Three</p></div></li>
                    <li><a href="#block"><img src="slider/images/example/4.jpg" class="circles" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>Four</p></div></li>
                    <li><a href="#cubeRandom"><img src="slider/images/example/5.jpg" class="circles" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>Five</p></div></li>
                    <li><a href="#block"><img src="slider/images/example/6.jpg" class="circles" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>Six</p></div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End of banner-->
</body>
</html>

My defaul.css

body {
/*background-color:#F2F2F2;*/
background-color: #FFF;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-weight: normal;
font-family: Arial;
}
.clear {
clear: both;
}
ul, li, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

.banner {
width: 1000px;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
/*margin:0px 0px -4px 0px;*/
z-index: 100;
}
.banner img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
my mobile.css.
@media only screen and (max-width:530px)
{
/*(common width:260px;)*/
#wrapper
{
width:260px;
}
.header
{
width:260px;
height:auto;
}
.logo
{
width:260px;
height:90px;
text-align:center;
}

.banner
{
width:100%;
}
.banner img
{
width:100%;
height:100px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your media query styles will only apply if they have higher specificity than your default styles, or same specificity but appear later in your stylesheet. One way to resolve this is to reorder your style rules. Another way is to add a second media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:531px)
{
    .banner {
        width: 1000px;
    }
}
```

Remove the width from the regular .banner style and let the media queries handle all the width rules.

Comment: I have removed .banner class in default.css and mobile.css.After that I have created in style.css @import 'secondmediaquery.css' then I have written.what you suggested to me.check the link http://vkacademy.in/banner/

Comment: how did you say regular style take priority.As there is any way to check?please see this link also what I have written in this website. I have done same thing http://chinmayavadavallikovai.com/  here it is coming properly.I don't understand what issue avaiable in the code?

Comment: I updated my answer with more detail. If this doesn't help, I recommend reading the following article to get a better understanding: http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/

Comment: ok .Sure I will read this. If possible. can you updated jquery banner according to your way.because each and every if we executed in real time that is great for me and others also.I will follow that in my code.since I have already done for another site. if write with your own way that is great.